# how to chain mysql query result into one variable

Tags: mysql, chain

I have a table with two columns: id and name.
I want to get the names into one variables, with commas between them.
John, Smith, Jacob,
and so on.
I tried this:

```
declare names varchar(5000);
set names="";  
select concat(concat(names,client_name),",") into names from tbl_clients;
```

but I got:

Error Code: 1172. Result consisted of more than one row

is there any way to do it?

Comment: Have a look at [group_concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) instead.

Comment: in Mysql you can assign a single result to a variable may be you table contain multiple values.GROUP BY should work for you

Comment: @ Joachim Isaksson, Huge thanks, it works perfectly.